# Is there a better way: my kludgy use of AddingManagedObjectContext?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Problem: kludgy use of AddingManagedObjectContext?

The app is  Universal Library Style CoreData. RootTableView has Book Category List, Fiction, Sci-Fi etc.
Addition of a book is done on second level BookListTableView via EditButton and then a newly appearing '+'  button. The third level displays book details tableview.

When the user touches the '+' button on the second level 'BookList' view, he has
already indicated that the book should by default have the category just selected on the
home BookCategoryList view. The new book will be an object unknown in the main MOC, and is placed in the addingMOC at the beginning of the insertion operation. I find that if I add the
user's desired category, say Sci-Fi, from the mainMOC  into the addingMOC, there is an
error at save: time, because, as I understand it, a ManagedObject can not exist in two different MOCs.

Because I want to perform this category addition as a convenience to the user, I go through
the following work around. I use a new stand-in category with the same
category Name, and add it to the new Book's property :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* categories;
```

,thus permitting the Books Details Table view in editing mode to display the name of the stand-in category object. Then when the user touches the Save button, just prior to :

```
[self.addingManagedObjectContext save:&error]
```

using objectID's, I remove the stand-in category from the new Book and then remove the same
 from the addingManagedObjectContext itself.

Follow this addingMOC save via:

NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
         [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(addControllerContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:
            self.addingManagedObjectContext];

the new Book (without category) in the addingMOC is merged into the mainMOC

I then insert the mainMOC's corresponding category to the new book
and then save the mainMOC to complete the saveAction.

This works for me, but it feels awkward. Can someone explain where I am wrong
and what I am missing? What is the correct and elegant cocoa way to handle this problem?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A managed object can exist in more than one managed object context, or more precisely managed objects that represent the same instance of a given entity can exist in more than one context.

Problems arise when you directly pass a managed object instance from one context to another especially when crossing thread boundaries as you have found.

The correct way to "pass" the managed object is to pass the `objectId` instead e.g.

```
//Context 1
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = myObjectInContext1.objectID;

//Context 2
NSManagedObject *myObjectInContext2 = [self.managedObjectContext2 objectWithID:objectID];
```

Alternatively you could also re-fetch the categories from the persistent store in the second context, which would give you valid category objects, and then pass some other value to indicate which of these objects to use e.g. a category id or title.

Comment: Thanks again. I have just eliminated many lines of useless and confusing code. I am so glad there are experts like you willing to give a hand.

Comment: If I'm the expert we're all doomed! I've just read far too much core data material trying to get my head round it all. Glad to help, I've had more than my fair share of help from stack overflow.